# implement Filter with multi property Angular 5 - javascript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, filtering, angular5

basically I want to implement a multi property filter that will filter Array of objects so I started to made a function multiFilter that accept a filter object that will selected from the end user who can select multi property such as 
brands
colors
name

this function that help me to pass the array which is the products as [arg1] , and filter object as [arg2] that have the values which need to be filtered by the end user

```js
    function multiFilter(array, filters) {
  let filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  // filters all elements passing the criteria
  return array.filter((item) => filterKeys.every((key) => (filters[key].indexOf(item[key]) !== -1)));
}


let products = 
[
  { name: "A", color: "pruple", size: 50 , brand : "nike", vendor : 'vendor 1 ' },

  { name: "A", color: "orange", size: 60 , brand : "nike", vendor : 'vendor 2 ' },

  { name: "A", color: "orange", size: 40 , brand : "nike", vendor : 'vendor 1 ' },

  { name: "A", color: "red", size: 50 , brand : "nike", vendor : 'vendor 1 ' },

  { name: "A", color: "red", size: 50 , brand : "nike", vendor : 'vendor 1 ' },

  { name: "A", color: "black", size: 50 , brand : "nike", vendor : 'vendor 1 ' },

  { name: "A", color: "black", size: 50 , brand : "nike", vendor : 'vendor 1 ' },

  { name: "B", color: "pruple", size: 50 , brand : "zara", vendor : 'vendor 2 ' },

  { name: "B", color: "orange", size: 60 , brand : "zara", vendor : 'vendor 2 ' },

  { name: "B", color: "orange", size: 40 , brand : "zara", vendor : 'vendor 2 ' },

  { name: "B", color: "red", size: 50 , brand : "zara", vendor : 'vendor 2 ' },

  { name: "B", color: "red", size: 50 , brand : "zara", vendor : 'vendor 2 ' },

  { name: "B", color: "black", size: 50 , brand : "zara", vendor : 'vendor 2 '},

  { name: "B", color: "black", size: 50 , brand : "zara", vendor : 'vendor 2 ' },
]
 
let filters = {

  name : ["A","B"],

  brand : ['nike','zara'],

   color: ["orange", "red" , 'black'],

   size: [40 , 70 , 50]

};

var filtered = multiFilter(products, filters);


console.info('Filtered');
console.log(filtered);
```

[you can find the clear code screenshot from here !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd7W4.jpg)

[The console result here !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Ewh.jpg)
my question here how to convert this javascript logic into Angular 5

how to made checkbox inputs that manage the filter object and pass the checked inputs into the multifiltered function that handled my products filter

[so i started to implement that but can't solve it any help ! - check stackbitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvdgms?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)